# SQLServer script to Postgres script conversion

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to convert the following stored procedure from SQL Server to Postgres This script returns multiple records. Please help me regarding this.

```
CREATE procEDURE [dbo].[EMS_DVS_EVALUATION_GetCourseListforallocation]                                                      
--[EMS_DVS_EVALUATION_GetCourseListforallocation] 'FAZZZZZ','NOVY02'                                                        
@authorid CHAR(7),                                                      
@examid CHAR(6),           
@roleid CHAR(4) = null                                                       
AS                                                          
BEGIN       

if  (@Roleid IS NULL)     
begin     
    select @roleid=RoleID from public..AdminUserGroup where UserID=@authorid        
end       

if(@Roleid = 'C012')           
begin                                                        
    SELECT  asm.scode
        ,cm.CourseName
        ,COUNT(ead.ASALID)   [Count]                          
        ,asm.CourseID[coursecode]                                  
    FROM iedbevaluation.ASMaster asm                                                     
    INNER JOIN iedbevaluation.EvaluationAllocationDetails ead                                                          
        ON asm.ASID = ead.ASID 
    INNER JOIN public.CourseMaster cm                                                          
        ON cm.CourseID= asm.courseid 
    INNER JOIN public.FacultyCourseEvaluationDetails fced 
        on fced.coursecode = asm.courseid             
    WHERE  lov='2'  
        and authorid IS NULL 
        and fced.EvaluationType in ('M','B')                                   
        and   fced.StatusFlag ='A' 
        AND fced.FUID=@authorid    
        and asm.coursetype=@examid             
    GROUP BY asm.scode,cm.CourseName ,asm.CourseID                                                 
    ORDER BY asm.scode 
end 

else    
begin          
    SELECT  asm.scode
        ,cm.CourseName
        ,COUNT(ead.ASALID)   [Count]                          
        ,asm.CourseID[coursecode]                                  
    FROM iedbevaluation.ASMaster asm                                                     
    INNER JOIN iedbevaluation.EvaluationAllocationDetails ead                                                          
        ON asm.ASID = ead.ASID 
    INNER JOIN public.CourseMaster cm                                                          
        ON cm.CourseID= asm.courseid 
    INNER JOIN public.FacultyCourseEvaluationDetails fced 
        on fced.coursecode = asm.courseid             
    WHERE  lov='1' 
        and authorid IS NULL 
        and fced.EvaluationType in ('E','B')                                
        and   fced.StatusFlag ='A' 
        AND fced.FUID=@authorid   
        and asm.coursetype=@examid             
GROUP BY asm.scode,cm.CourseName ,asm.CourseID                                                 
ORDER BY asm.scode      
end   

END
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question doesn't show any effort on behalf of OP. He/she didn't even try to convert the query from one RDBMS to another. This is basically asking the community to do somebody's work.

Answer (score 4):

Some basic rules:

- parameters or variables are not prefixed with `@` in PL/pgSQL (because `@` is invalid in an identifier in SQL)
- however, it is highly recommended to prefix parameters with some distinct prefix to make sure their names to not conflict with column names. Many people use the prefix `p_` but of course you can use something different.
- every statement has to be terminated with a `;` (which you [should be doing in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons) as well)
- square brackets are illegal in an identifier in SQL. You should remove them. If you need case sensitive identifiers you have to use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) but I **strongly** recommend to **not** do that however.
- to return a result set you need a function that is defined as `returns table()` - I assumed the data types of the result columns based on their names. Most probably you will have to adjust that.
- the return the result of a query from a PL/pgSQL function, you need `return query`. You can't just put a query into the code.

Putting all that together, the following should get you started:

```
create function ems_dvs_evaluation_getcourselistforallocation(p_authorid char(7), p_examid CHAR(6), p_roleid CHAR(4) default null)
    returns table (scode text, course_name text, course_count bigint, course_code integer)
AS
$func$
begin

  if (roleid is null) then     
      select RoleID 
        into p_roleid
      from AdminUserGroup 
      where UserID = p_authorid;
  end if;

  if (p_roleid = 'C012') then 
    return query                                      
      SELECT  asm.scode
             ,cm.CourseName
             ,COUNT(ead.ASALID)
             ,asm.CourseID
      FROM iedbevaluation.ASMaster asm                                                     
      INNER JOIN iedbevaluation.EvaluationAllocationDetails ead                                                          
          ON asm.ASID = ead.ASID 
      INNER JOIN public.CourseMaster cm                                                          
          ON cm.CourseID= asm.courseid 
      INNER JOIN public.FacultyCourseEvaluationDetails fced 
          on fced.coursecode = asm.courseid             
      WHERE  lov='2'  
          and authorid IS NULL 
          and fced.EvaluationType in ('M','B')                                   
          and fced.StatusFlag = 'A' 
          AND fced.FUID = p_authorid
          and asm.coursetype = p_exampid
      GROUP BY asm.scode,cm.CourseName ,asm.CourseID                                                 
      ORDER BY asm.scode;
  else  
    return query                                      
      SELECT  asm.scode
             ,cm.CourseName
             ,COUNT(ead.ASALID) 
             ,asm.CourseID
      FROM iedbevaluation.ASMaster asm                                                     
      INNER JOIN iedbevaluation.EvaluationAllocationDetails ead                                                          
          ON asm.ASID = ead.ASID 
      INNER JOIN public.CourseMaster cm                                                          
          ON cm.CourseID= asm.courseid 
      INNER JOIN public.FacultyCourseEvaluationDetails fced 
          on fced.coursecode = asm.courseid             
      WHERE  lov='1' 
          and authorid IS NULL 
          and fced.EvaluationType in ('E','B')                                
          and fced.StatusFlag ='A' 
          AND fced.FUID = p_authorid   
          and asm.coursetype= p_examid             
    GROUP BY asm.scode,cm.CourseName, asm.CourseID                                                 
    ORDER BY asm.scode;
  end if;

END;
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

Note that if the column `lov` is a number, you should compare that to a number: `where lov = 1`

For more information about PL/pgSQL syntax and functions, please [read the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)